# How to get the path of a project using EnvDTE

Tags: c#, envdte

**Big picture:**
I am working on an Extension Tools for Visual Studio 2015. Currently I have a Member Finder windows form responsible to display all the Methods and Properties inside a project.

**Problem**
I also need to display the physical path of the files containing the Members And starting from the Project name. I have searched and figured out that this could be achievable using the library of EnvDTE. I have also worked on the library but unfortunately could not manage the issue. Here is a picture of the Member Finder window which needs the path the member at the end of the each list box item.

Member Finder Without a Path

[image]

Any idea kindly appreciated.

Comment: There is no Visual Studio 15. There's Visual Studio 2015, which has an internal version number of 14. If/When there's a next version of Visual Studio, it is likely that it will receive the number 15 (and, historically, Microsoft have offered previews/CTPs using those version numbers)

Comment: Yes, you are right! by "15" I meant "2015"

Answer (score 1):

Using the automation model (EnvDTE) you can get the file name with path of an EnvDTE.Project using:

- EnvDTE.Project.FullName
- In some cases (WebSite projects) using the EnvDTE.Project.Properties collection, with a property name "FullPath".